# How initialize undefined property with contener variable

Tags: javascript, typescript

I don't know is undefined this property. My browser console is throwing error undefined property. I do not use constructor class. I use this property in `app.component.ts` in similar class.

```
  private page: {
    idPage: string;
    isScrolling: boolean;
    scrollElement: { scrollTop: any; scrollHeight: any; };
    element: HTMLElement;
  };
```

How do use or initializing this property for TypeScript 3.5 and Angular 8.

Error variable property undefined is mistake:
[image: Error variable property undefined is mistake]

Answer (score 0):

This class member may be initialized as follows (random values):

```
this.page = {
   idPage: 'x',
   isScrolling: true,
   scrollElement: { scrollTop: 1, scrollHeight: 2 },
   element: new HTMLDivElement()
}
```

Comment: What use in code palace to this? Constructor class to use this property?? I don`t now please help.

Comment: The class member may be best initialized in the `class constructor` or in the `ngOnInit` method. I don't have enough information about your project to give a more specific answer.